# SSL not working on nginx Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, nginx

I have SSL from namecheap and activated. After activated I download the file mydomain.crt and mydomain.ca-bundle. Then combine them into one.

$ cat mydomain.crt mydomain.ca-bundle >> mydomain_chain.crt

My server is VPS LEMP stack on digitalocean.

I put mydomain_chain.crt and mydomain.key int /etc/nginx/ssl folder.

Then edit the nginx host file as follow -:
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```html
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
 
    server_name mydomain.co www.mydomain.co;
 
    rewrite ^/(.*) https://www.mydomain.co/$1 permanent;
   }

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 http2 default_server;
 
    server_name mydomain.co www.mydomain.co;
 
 ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
 
 root /var/www/html;
 
 index index.html index.htm;
 
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain_chain.crt;
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain.key;
 
 location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
 }
   }
```

But it is not working when I type https://www.mydomain.co

May I know what configuration is missing.

Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

thanks you so much for your help.

I found the problem. In digitalocean, if you use one click LEMP 16.04, your nginx host configuration file is /etc/nginx/sites-available/digitalocean instead of /etc/nginx/sites-available/default. That's why whatever I changed in default, it does not effected.

Comment: This is the same case that happen to me as I use the one-click LEMP. Thanks for sharing!

p.s.: I rename the `digitalocean` host configuration file (`mv digitalocean digitaloceanDefault`) and run `sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` to set `default` run on nginx startup.

Answer (score 0):

SSL isn't enables on IPv6 but other than that, your configuration seems workable (the redirect to HTTPS is somewhat unusual but if you explicitly tried https:// that won't matter).

Comment: I tried wget
wget -S -O /dev/null https://www.mydomain.co
--2016-10-12 13:45:53--  https://www.mydomain.co/
Resolving www.mydomain.co (www.mydomain.co)... 128.199.xxx.xxx
Connecting to www.mydomain.co (www.mydomain.co)|128.199.xxx.xxx|:443... failed: Connection refused.

Comment: but all nginx full is allow in firewall

Comment: You're most likely either blocking port 443 or you have a reverse proxy, this is no longer an issue with your NGINX configuration but rather with your overall server setup.

Comment: Thanks for reply. 
There is no 443 in nmap info. I have no idea how to open 443
root@web-lemp-2gb-sgp1-01:~# nmap localhost

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-10-12 15:53 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000012s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open ssh
80/tcp open http
3306/tcp open mysql

Comment: You have to look at your firewall (most likely iptables, try `iptables - L`)

Comment: Also, I forgot to ask and just assumed you did but I'm thinking it's highly likely you simply didn't reload your NGINX configuration. Did you reload NGINX after editing your configuration?